# NotSerializableException on serialization of objects currently shown by Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, vaadin

I get a NotSerializableException when I want to serialize an Object that is currently shown by Vaadin.

The structure is like this:

Vaadin UI <--- serialize / deserialize --- > Hibernate/JPA Postgres Database

Vaadin shows objects that are requested from the Database via IPC,
but when I manipulate the object and want to save it again by
serializing it and sending it over to the controller I get the following Exception:

```css
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
 at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1118)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I tried to:

Request -> manipulate -> Save | works

Request -> show in Vaadin -> manipulate in Vaadin-> Save | doesn't work

Why does the Serializer want to AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext and is there a workaround? Can I remove it beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Spring components are usually not serializable (or should not be serialized at all).

Injecting Spring components in Vaadin components linked to a Vaadin UI is tricky because them should be declared as `transient` and re-populated after deserialization..

I wrote a small library [jdal-aop](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop) to ease the process, using spring-aop serializable proxies.

for example

```
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    @Autowired
    @SerializableProxy  // make this Dao serializable
    private CustomerDao customerDao;
}
```

It could be useful for you.