# EnableRedisHttpSession fails with vaadin

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-session, vaadin4spring

Running this project http://github.com/khauser/microservices4vaadin, which shall act as a sample vaadin microservice structure with Oauth2.0 I'm having the problem that the vaadin Service could not read/deserialize the session entries from Redis. Here's the stacktrace:

```
2015-12-21 17:15:08.409 DEBUG 10252 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@5d37ce73
2015-12-21 17:15:08.426 ERROR 10252 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/ui].[dispatcherServlet]  : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/ui] threw exception

org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id d6106b74-4879-31cb-9dfc-ac10c3b1b96b: no factory registered for this id
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id d6106b74-4879-31cb-9dfc-ac10c3b1b96b: no factory registered for this id
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:39) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id d6106b74-4879-31cb-9dfc-ac10c3b1b96b: no factory registered for this id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1428) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1810) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:557) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I think the deserialization stops when reading "sessionAttr:org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext" but I'm not sure.

Is there something I can do about that? I really would appreciate some help.

**Some updates:**

I'm really not in this but as far I understand DefaultListableBeanFactory tries to find the needed "BeanResolvers" (or the "deserializing" factory itself... I'm really not in this) with a wrong UUID in the serializationId-attribute.

Each service registers the factory under its own UUID:

```
2015-12-22 10:44:35.674  INFO 12408 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17f9344b: startup date [Tue Dec 22 10:44:35 CET 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@19c65cdc
2015-12-22 10:44:40.592 DEBUG 12408 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17f9344b: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@408613cc: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,vaadinApplication]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5d8bafa9
2015-12-22 10:44:42.346  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'hystrixFeature' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]]
2015-12-22 10:44:42.422  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'oauth2RemoteResource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2RemoteResource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$BaseConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2RemoteResource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$BaseConfiguration.class]]
2015-12-22 10:44:42.483  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-12-22 10:44:42.593  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]]
2015-12-22 10:44:42.663  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/klhauser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.1.RELEASE/bb42e637833fd9c17df6092790d6209872e0bd65/spring-integration-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2015-12-22 10:44:42.671  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2015-12-22 10:44:42.806  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2015-12-22 10:44:43.382  INFO 12408 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=aa3a4b90-c1c2-307e-b5b8-f7b98056e662
```

My opinion here is that it shouldn't be a UUID, but instead a common known identifier.

Comment: The UUIDs are different because of a diffrent set of "BeanResolvers" for each service. See line 235 in GenericScope: `id = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(names.getBytes()).toString();`

@DaveSyer: Do you have an idea what I can do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was was able to come around this kind of failure. With:

```
private final static String SESSION_SERIALIZATION_ID = "microservices4vaadin";

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Bean
public String overwriteSerializationId() {
    BeanFactory beanFactory = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).setSerializationId(SESSION_SERIALIZATION_ID);
    return "overwritten";
}
```

now every microservice registers it's bean factory under the same serialization id.

Sadly I run into the next problem, which seems to be more complicated (See here: [NotSerializableException on serialization of objects currently shown by Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388542/notserializableexception-on-serialization-of-objects-currently-shown-by-vaadin)).